# How to check gem dependencies from a specific version of a Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know you can do this:

```
gem dependency ar_mailer --remote
```

or this:

```
gem dependency rails_admin --reverse-dependencies
```

But I want to know the dependencies from a past version of rails_admin. How do I specify that?

Comment: Exactly from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
gem dependency --help


gem dependency rails_admin --version
```

---

**update by rmagnum2002**

without --version

```
user@user:~/projects/new_work$ gem dependency devise
Gem devise-3.0.4
  bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
  orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
  railties (< 5, >= 3.2.6)
  warden (~> 1.2.3)

Gem devise-3.2.2
  bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
  orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
  railties (< 5, >= 3.2.6)
  thread_safe (~> 0.1)
  warden (~> 1.2.3)
```

with --version

```
user@user:~/projects/new_work$ gem dependency devise --version 3.0.4
Gem devise-3.0.4
  bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
  orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
  railties (< 5, >= 3.2.6)
  warden (~> 1.2.3)
```

when no such version found installed on your system or bundler

```
user@user:~/projects/new_work$ gem dependency devise --version 3.0.6
No gems found matching devise (= 3.0.6)
```

Comment: Nice idea but I tried it and it didn't work: gem dependency rails_admin --version 0.5.9            No gems found matching rails_admin (= 0.5.9)

Comment: @asolberg it didn't worked with --version cause you don't have that version installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gem dependency -rv 5.1.2 /^rails$/
Gem rails-5.1.2
  actioncable (= 5.1.2)
  actionmailer (= 5.1.2)
  actionpack (= 5.1.2)
  actionview (= 5.1.2)
  activejob (= 5.1.2)
  activemodel (= 5.1.2)
  activerecord (= 5.1.2)
  activesupport (= 5.1.2)
  bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
  railties (= 5.1.2)
  sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
```

Options:

```
-v, --version VERSION            Specify version of gem to dependency
-r, --remote                     Restrict operations to the REMOTE domain
```

P.S. `rails` depends on `bundler`? O.o